# CouchDB inaccessible on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, couchdb

I am using an Amazon EC2 "micro" instance as a testbed for a new project, one that is supposed to use CouchDB. Although the DBMS has installed correctly (via pacman; I'm using ArchLinux) and appears to start I cannot access Futon at all. This is in spite of me opening the necessary port in the security group for the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you opened the appropriate port on your firewall as well?
Have you set the bind_address in /etc/couchdb/local.ini to 0.0.0.0?